# $\frac{5}{3\cdot2!}+\frac{5\cdot7}{3^2\cdot3!}+\frac{5\cdot7\cdot9}{3^3\cdot4!}+\space...\space=\space?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

The original question is just below.

$$2+\frac{5}{3\cdot2!}+\frac{5\cdot7}{3^2\cdot3!}+\frac{5\cdot7\cdot9}{3^3\cdot4!}+\space...\space=\space?$$

I tried to express it with the summation notation but was really confused by the geometric series in the numerator. I then decided to use double factorial. I don't know if I made the correct thing to start with but that was all I could afford.

$$2+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2k+3)!!}{3^{k+1}\space\cdot\space(k+1)!}$$

I don't have the answer. Could you please explain how to solve this question? As you see, I couldn't really do much, so it would be great if you could clearly explain each step.